# Returning numbers divisible by 3 within an array using a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to return numbers to the console that are divisible by 3 within the array below, using a for loop as seen below.

It is returning numbers 2-9 into the console, but not the ones divisible by 3? I am stumped? What am I doing wrong?

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(i % 3){
       console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are also using the the loop index for your `if` statement instead of the number in the `numbers` array. I assume you would rather check the number in the array to see if it is divisible by 3

Comment: Your logic is wrong in this case. Your 'var i' does not represent a number inside numbers array. Your if statement should find search for numbers[i] % 3 == 0

Comment: Your code find numbers which have a position not divisible by 3

Answer (score 10):

The `if` statement branches based on the result of the conditional statement. `if(i % 3){` will return `true` anytime the result of the modulo operation is not `0` because any non-zero number converts to `true`.

The statement should be:  `if(i % 3 === 0){` because you only want to branch into the `true` section if you divide by 3 and the remainder is `0`.

Next, you are using your loop index as the number to operate on, but you need to use the array item with the index of your loop counter `numbers[i]`, not `i`.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0){
       console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, a simpler approach here may be to use **[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**, which loops over the array and returns a new array with the values you specify:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var results = numbers.filter(function(num){
  return num % 3 === 0;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: You could also make it `if(!(i % 3)) {`

Comment: Thanks. That's so obvious, I should have seen that. I am new to Javascript. :)

Quick question, when I edit the code with the above, I get 1,4,7 and 10, not the numbers that are divisible by 3. Am I missing something else?

Comment: *"`if(i % 3){` will always return `true`  because every number is divisible by 3."* `Boolean(3 % 3) => false` ... ;)

Comment: Also, you filter callback should just be `return num % 3 === 0;`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. I had a different solution that needed that and then changed it to `.filter()`, which doesn't.

Comment: The first sentence is still incorrect though. `i % 3` is not always true-ish (as shown in my first comment).

Comment: Expanding on what @FelixKling said, any number that is divisible by 3 with a 0 remainder will return false in `if(i % 3)` since the result `0` is a "falsy" value.

Comment: @AndrewLohr That's exactly what Felix said. That point is conceded and the answer already updated.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see what you're saying, but the wording of the answer is confusing imo. The statement *you can divide any number by 3* is absolutely true, but *every number is divisible by 3* isn't. The very definition of the word "divisible" implies there is no remainder.

Comment: `if(i % 3){` will enter the branch if `i` is *not* divisible by 3. Your first statement is still unclear.

Comment: But for `3` it does not enter the `true` branch?!

Comment: 66% is not really "usually" and "just about every number"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. Answer has been updated for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

numbers.forEach(n => {
  if (n % 3 === 0) console.log(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if` statement. Please see the example.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0){
       console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that fixed it. :)

Comment: @CaliCap you were really close. Sometimes you get tunnel vision and need a second pair of eyes to catch these things. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you are doing wrong is that you are using **i** instead of numbers[i] and secondly you are not comparing it to **0**. It should be something like:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] % 3==0){
    console.log(numbers[i]);}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

You can also achieve by using **Unary Negation Operator (Exclamation Mark)** with help of [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

**DEMO**

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

console.log(numbers.reduce((r,v)=>!(v%3)?r.concat(v):r,[]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

With help of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**DEMO**

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

console.log(numbers.filter(v=>!(v%3)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```